# Finding the perfect numbers between 1 - 1000

Tags: java

This code was made to find all the perfect numbers between 1 and 1000. A perfect number, is a number where all of it's divisors add up to that number.

For example:

`6` is divisible by `3,2, and 1` and`3+2+1 = 6`. Therefore `6` is a perfect number.

```
public class Perfect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int LIMIT = 1000;
        boolean isPerfect = false;
        int i;
        for(i = 2; i < LIMIT; i++) { 
            isPerfect = isNumPerfect(i);
            if(isPerfect) {
                System.out.println(i + " is a perfect number");
            }
        }
    }
    public static boolean isNumPerfect(int i) {
        boolean isPerfect = false;
        int sum = 1;
        int x;
        for(x = 2; x <= i / 2; x++) {
            if(i % x == 0) {
                sum += x;
            }
        }
        if(sum == i) {
            isPerfect = true;
        }
        return isPerfect;
    }
}
```

What are some ways that I can improve on this code? More specifically, ways to shorten it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need variables like `isPerfect`.  Loop variables should be declared in the for-loop header to limit their scope.  Both of these changes simplify your code just a bit and improve readability.

I also suggest renaming `i` → `n` and `x` → `i`.  `x` has the connotation of being a floating-point number, and `i` has the connotation of being a loop counter.

Here is your program with just those recommended changes.

```
public class Perfect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int LIMIT = 1000;
        for (int i = 2; i < LIMIT; i++) { 
            if (isNumPerfect(i)) {
                System.out.println(i + " is a perfect number");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNumPerfect(int n) {
        int sum = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        return sum == n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to shorten it, there are only 3 perfect numbers up to 1000: just list 6, 28, and 496.

If you're trying to speed it up, an array of 1000 numbers is small enough to stay reasonably cache-resident: you can compute all divisor sums *together* faster than you can compute each of them one at a time.  This is similar to how you can sieve a long interval for primes much faster than you can test each number individually for primality.  Code fragment:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n/2; i++) {
  for(int x=2*i; x<=n; x+=i) {
    divisor_sum[x] += i;
  }
}
```

The length of the inner loop is O(n/i), which gets small very quickly, making the total cost O(n log n), whereas your double loop is O(n^2).

Comment: You're right. My old answer made a silly mistake misreading the way numbers were generated. Thank you for correcting. It did not deserve as many upvotes as it did.

Comment: I'm trying to shorten the length of the code, but I want the program to find out which are the perfect numbers, I don't want to just print them out.